# How can i implement QOS on internet traffic in windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, qos

Is there any way i can implement QOS in windows 7 by any software. I have PC where i download data all day. I download all data from one site. I want that when i visit other http site then i get the full bandwidth and that download gets least prioroty but when i finish that then download gets full BW.

I know i can do that in cisco router but i want to know if that can be done via any software in windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to do via Group Policy under

`Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings`

I have not personally used it so I can't attest to its value, but it seems to have all the right options. Create a new policy there and specify the executable name for your downloading program on page 2 of the wizard.

Microsoft have a tip on it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771283.aspx).